# Sitecore 7.2 firing JavaScript on component when it is added to component zone

Tags: javascript, sitecore, sitecore7, sitecore7.2

This seem to just be an issue with Sitecore. But when I have a component, like a slider, that fires JavaScript on load, and drop it in a component zone, it does so on client side. So the JavaScript does not  fire until I push the save button or reload the page. This is because the JavaScript in run on document ready.

Does anyone have a working solution they have been using to solve this issue? I am thinking about firing the load event when page is in editor mode and act normal in non-editor mode.

Comment: This question is rather old. @dnstommy, did you managed to find solution for your problem?

Comment: No, ended up just putting up a grayscale image when the slider was dropped. And then loaded it for real when it was loaded with the page.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to disable your slider's JavaScript when in PageEditor mode.  To do this check the JavaScript property `Sitecore.PageModes.PageEditor` which can be done with the following function:

```
function isPageEditor() {
    if (typeof Sitecore == "undefined") {
        return false;
    }
    if (typeof Sitecore.PageModes == "undefined" || Sitecore.PageModes == null) {
        return false;
    }
    return Sitecore.PageModes.PageEditor != null;
}
```

Then your JavaScript for the slider component would be something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if (isPageEditor() == false) {
        //slider setup code here   
    }
}
```

Comment: I like your solution, but I am looking to make my JavaScript turn on. It is currently not working because my slider code is loaded via RequireJS, on the document ready for the whole page. Which means that when I drop my slider on the page in edit mode, the function is not being told to run. It looks like I am going to have to fire an event for the slider component when the page is in page editor mode and the slider HTML is drawn, to make the slider JS run. This would force it to run even if I just dropped it on the page.

Comment: Ah I see I'm with you now. Normally people want to do the opposite ;-)  I wouldn't normally recommend this; but if you had some javascript inside your component - or at least a call to the initialisation bit, it might work then. I will update my answer shortly...

Comment: We are working on a solution. We are using slick carousel and it draws all the slider images, resizes and finally makes it a slider. All via Javascript. When I drop my control on the page, it just draws boxes of HTML. I need to make Slick run its code and make a slider for the user. Thank you for your help. Your code is appreciated.